# Admob's Adchoices to open in Safari instead of a webview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, safari, admob

I am guessing this is a new type of ad for Admob.

Before, every time I click an ad returned by Admob, it opens the app store or a link in safari. But now, if I click on an ad that has the blue arrow on the right, it just shows a webview with the link. I am wondering if this can be avoided. I want the link to directly open in safari whenever I click the blue arrow. I noticed that the number of clicks for my ads have significantly decreased since this kind of ad appeared. So I'm thinking this may be related to the ad not opening in a browser.

Thank you very much for your help.